# asp.net core Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I created TagHelper

namespace is **SomeName.Framework.TagHelpers**

class name **ValidationTagHelper**

I'm registered my TagHelper in **_ViewImports** in project **SomeName.Web**

```
@using SomeName.Framework.TagHelpers

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, SomeName.Framework.TagHelpers
```

But still get error

> Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'SomeName.Framework.TagHelpers'. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'SomeName.Framework.TagHelpers, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Also I try

@addTagHelper "*, SomeName.Framework.TagHelpers"

Comment: I think, you need to specify folder, not assembly. For example, if project is in `"proj-name/src/proj-name.csproj"`, then correct directive is `@addTagHelper "*, proj-name"` regardless of your namespace. see if this helps.

Comment: Did it worked? Please share your answer so that it will help others :)

Comment: Yes. Big thx to you!!!

Comment: @Sanket it might be useful to others as well if you post your comment as an answer, and that gets accepted.

Comment: @superjos Posted as answer. Hopefully Greg will accept as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In such cases, you need to specify folder, not assembly.

For example, if project is in `"proj-name/src/proj-name.csproj"`, then correct directive is @`addTagHelper "*, proj-name"` regardless of your namespace.